# How can I run all test files that are in different folders using mocha?

Tags: testing, path, mocha.js

I want to run my mocha test using `npm test` the problem is that the tests may vary their location.

The locations may be `lib/modules/somefolder/test/*-test.js` or `lib/modules/somefolder/anotherfolder/test/*-test.js`

Currently my test script is like this `node_modules/.bin/mocha lib/modules/*/test/*-test.js --reporter spec` but this won't find the test files located in the second location.

Is there any way to find the tests in both locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by doing `./**/*-test.js`. This should find any files with `-test.js` in the name in any directory relative to the one you are in.

Comment: Only for tests which have a common ancestor folder, Mocha will run **all** the tests file in the common folder, which is sometimes unwanted. If you have 10 folders under a common one, and you only want to run tests for a few together, just run it like so: `mocha src/a/**/*.test.js src/c/**/*.test.js`